# Microsoft bot framework And Messanger mobile notification

Tags: facebook, botframework, facebook-messenger, facebook-messenger-bot

I've created a bot with Microsoft bot framework for Messenger.
All work great. i can recieve and send message to messanger but in messanger mobile push notification not work. I omit the property notification_type because facebook guide say

> notification_type is optional; by default, messages will be REGULAR
>   push notification type

It is a Framework bug?

My code:

```
ConnectorClient connector = new ConnectorClient(new Uri(servUri), microsoftAppId: appId, microsoftAppPassword: pass);
ResourceResponse conversationId = await connector.Conversations.CreateDirectConversationAsync(botAccount, userAccount);
IMessageActivity activity = Activity.CreateMessageActivity();

activity.Id = conversationId.Id;
activity.Type = ActivityTypes.Message;
activity.From = botAccount;
activity.Conversation = conversation;
activity.Recipient = userAccount;
activity.Text = "hello";

await connector.Conversations.SendToConversationAsync((Activity)activity);
```

Comment: You have to make sure that your user had clicked on "Get Started" button first

Comment: @VũTuấnAnh you can omit the start conversation. Otherwise the user alredy clicked start conversation

Comment: Consider posting your answer in the "Your Answer" section rather thin in the question.

Comment: I'm having this issue also. Messages should be channel-agnostic, in that you should not have to add special data to your message/activity to make a notification happen on Messenger. Still looking for solutions.

Comment: I have a potential solution, will post below.

Answer (score 1):

I've used activity.ChannelData and all work good
I post my solution, can be useful to someone

Add the attachment to the activity:

```
activity.ChannelData = new FacebookChannelData()
{
    Attachment = GetFacebookAttachment()
};
```

create the attachment:

```
private static FacebookAttachment GetFacebookAttachment()
{
    return new FacebookAttachment()
    {
        Payload = new GenericTemplate
        {
            Elements = new[] {
                    new TemplateElements(){
                    Title = "my title",
                    ItemUrl = "https://example.com",
                    ImageUrl = "https://example.com/test.jpg",
                    Subtitle = "subtitle",
                    Buttons = new[] {
                        new TemplateButtons() {
                            Type = "web_url",
                            Url = "https://example.com",
                            Title = "button title"
                        }
                    }
                    }
                }
        }
    };
}
```

and then the classes:

```
public class FacebookChannelData
{
    public FacebookChannelData() {
        this.NotificationType = "REGULAR";
    }

    [JsonProperty("notification_type")]
    public string NotificationType { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("attachment")]
    public FacebookAttachment Attachment { get; internal set; }
}

public class FacebookAttachment
{
    public FacebookAttachment()
    {
        this.Type = "template";
    }

    [JsonProperty("type")]
    public string Type { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("payload")]
    public dynamic Payload { get; set; }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return this.Payload.ToString();
    }
}

public class GenericTemplate
{
    public GenericTemplate()
    {
        this.TemplateType = "generic";
    }

    [JsonProperty("template_type")]
    public string TemplateType { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("elements")]
    public TemplateElements[] Elements { get; set; }
}

public class TemplateElements
{
    [JsonProperty("title")]
    public string Title { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("item_url")]
    public string ItemUrl { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("image_url")]
    public string ImageUrl { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("subtitle")]
    public string Subtitle { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("buttons")]
    public TemplateButtons[] Buttons { get; set; }
}

public class TemplateButtons
{
    [JsonProperty("type")]
    public string Type { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("url")]
    public string Url { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("title")]
    public string Title { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("payload")]
    public string Payload { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: The key point here is that you have to specify a ChannelData - any ChannelData - on your Activity in order to get a notification.

Answer (score 1):

`notification_type` IS optional - but only in the context of when you're actually specifying a ChannelData on your activity.

So just add (given that you're `using Newtonsoft.Json.Linq;`)

```
        activity.ChannelData = JObject.FromObject(new
        {
            notification_type = "REGULAR"
        });
```

and you'll get your notification, provided that your client app has not disabled notifications.